# Appropriate mirror type (self-adhesive/drill-based) for outside of wardrobe door

Tags: drill, mirror

I'd like to fix mirrors on the outside of each of [this](https://www.xxxlutz.at/p/mid-you-drehtuerenschrank-in-wei-000380056821) wardrobe's four wooden doors:
[image]
[image]

Easiest would be to use self-sticking square mirrors such as [this](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/LIGHTENING/dp/B07SZCNHZG/ref=sr_1_7?crid=29KUK4JQHWLRY&keywords=spiegel%20selbstklebend&qid=1650184248&sprefix=spiegel%20selbstklebend%2Caps%2C156&sr=8-7) one. But several reviewers report having had those fall off after some time, which is disastrous with children around. Additionally, I'd have a slight preference for a single, tall mirror on each of the large doors, rather than 2 square ones above the other; self-adhesives appear to only come as smallish rectangular ones, probably due to the weight limit imposed by the adhesive.

The alternative that seems to me better (if a bit more difficult to install), is to drill woodscrews into the door for plastic/metal brackets (two underneath, two on the sides), which would allow for a larger and possibly more stably-affixed mirror like [this](https://www.ikea.com/de/de/p/lettan-spiegel-80435305/).

Either way, the mirror would have to be steady enough to withhold the wear & tear of a wardrobe door opening 2-3 times per day, without danger of falling off.

Are there any other pros&cons I've not already thought of for each of these two alternatives? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Get the metal glass / mirror holders, usually chromed, as better than plastic. Available as corner and side...

Comment: So you wouldn't recommend the self-adhesive option?

Comment: You already gave a good reason against the self-adhesive option. I gave you my considered opinion - the metal brackets I have used in the past have never failed...

Comment: Indeed, thanks Mike.

Comment: Use a full width u-shaped track at the bottom — you’ll be able to screw it in solidly and it’ll hold all the weight of the mirror. Then little clips (one per side, two at the top) will be all you need to stabilize. You’ll be able to find little clips that slide in and are quite subtle.

Comment: Consider a plastic mirror, as well, both for "lightness when applied to a door" and "less prone to break" (balanced with "more prone to scratch.")

Comment: Many thanks @AloysiusDefenestrate! Would you be able to provide an example link to such clips and u-shaped track, so I know what to look for in the hardware store? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ecnerwal! The plastic mirrors I found, such as [this](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Self-Adhesive-Non-Glass-Decoration-Decorative-Frameless/dp/B08YKB1375/ref=sr_1_3?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=18ITUH8FSZV6F&keywords=kunststoffspiegel&qid=1650226773&sprefix=fingerling%2Caps%2C165&sr=8-3), don't offer the same image quality, but you`re right that they do have their advantages.

Comment: I have used both mirror hangers and silicone adhesive dots in several locations. Why belt & suspenders approach? Door skins are very thin and I have had a mirror break loose when the kids slammed the door, and the mirror came off on to a tile floor, just lucky she was running out to play and not inside as there was glass everywhere. I added several blobs of silicone adhesive top middle and bottom with the mirror hangers that mirror is still in place 20+ years later, I did the same on my current home with solid wood doors , why take a chance use both. If needed adhesive removal use dental floss

Comment: Side clips: https://www.dkhardware.com/nickel-plated-adjustable-mirror-clip-set-for-1-4-seamed-mirror-64114-product-9982.html

Comment: For the track, google ‘mirror track’ or ‘j mirror track’

Comment: I wonder if drilling those brackets into a wooden door works to hold with them a round mirror like [this one](https://www.obi.at/spiegel/mirrors-more-dekospiegel-esra-metall-goldfarbig-50-cm/p/1416056), or if that would be too heavy, since it's not really propped from underneath as with the rectangular ones.